Adding Group of Symbols to TradingView Indicator
I have an RSI table and have two groups of symbols that are working for this tradingview indicator.  I added a third group and now have a syntax error.
I need help to remove the syntax error so the indicator will work. Syntax error starts at the variable u01 = symGrp=='Group1'?v01 :v21 :v41
The issue is with the last part which is ':v41'.  Did I add this part incorrectly? Should I be using a comma or colon?
t42 = input.symbol('FTNT',  group = 'Group3 Symbols', inline = 'Group3 s42')
t43 = input.symbol('NOW',  group = 'Group3 Symbols', inline = 'Group3 s43')
t44 = input.symbol('OKTA',  group = 'Group3 Symbols', inline = 'Group3 s44')
t45 = input.symbol('PANW',  group = 'Group3 Symbols', inline = 'Group3 s45')
t46 = input.symbol('PLTR',  group = 'Group3 Symbols', inline = 'Group3 s46')
t47 = input.symbol('ZS',  group = 'Group3 Symbols', inline = 'Group3 s47')
t48 = input.symbol('ADI',  group = 'Group3 Symbols', inline = 'Group3 s48')
t49 = input.symbol('AMAT',  group = 'Group3 Symbols', inline = 'Group3 s49')
t50 = input.symbol('ASML',  group = 'Group3 Symbols', inline = 'Group3 s50')
t51 = input.symbol('AVGO',  group = 'Group3 Symbols', inline = 'Group3 s51')
t52 = input.symbol('KLAC',  group = 'Group3 Symbols', inline = 'Group3 s52')
t53 = input.symbol('LRCX',  group = 'Group3 Symbols', inline = 'Group3 s53')
t54 = input.symbol('TSM',  group = 'Group3 Symbols', inline = 'Group3 s54')
t55 = input.symbol('TXN',  group = 'Group3 Symbols', inline = 'Group3 s55')
t56 = input.symbol('APD',  group = 'Group3 Symbols', inline = 'Group3 s56')
t57 = input.symbol('CTVA',  group = 'Group3 Symbols', inline = 'Group3 s57')
t58 = input.symbol('DOW',  group = 'Group3 Symbols', inline = 'Group3 s58')
t59 = input.symbol('ECL',  group = 'Group3 Symbols', inline = 'Group3 s59')
t60 = input.symbol('FCX',  group = 'Group3 Symbols', inline = 'Group3 s60')


// SHOW THE SYMBOLS
u01 = symGrp=='Group1'?v01 :v21 :v41
u02 = symGrp=='Group1'?v02 :v22 :v42
u03 = symGrp=='Group1'?v03 :v23 :v43
u04 = symGrp=='Group1'?v04 :v24 :v44
u05 = symGrp=='Group1'?v05 :v25 :v45
u06 = symGrp=='Group1'?v06 :v26 :v46
u07 = symGrp=='Group1'?v07 :v27 :v47
u08 = symGrp=='Group1'?v08 :v28 :v48
u09 = symGrp=='Group1'?v09 :v29 :v49
u10 = symGrp=='Group1'?v10 :v30 :v50
u11 = symGrp=='Group1'?v11 :v31 :v51
u12 = symGrp=='Group1'?v12 :v32 :v52
u13 = symGrp=='Group1'?v13 :v33 :v53
u14 = symGrp=='Group1'?v14 :v34 :v54
u15 = symGrp=='Group1'?v15 :v35 :v55
u16 = symGrp=='Group1'?v16 :v36 :v56
u17 = symGrp=='Group1'?v17 :v37 :v57
u18 = symGrp=='Group1'?v18 :v38 :v58
u19 = symGrp=='Group1'?v19 :v39 :v59
u20 = symGrp=='Group1'?v20 :v40 :v60


With the information you provided, it’s difficult to answer your question.
Could you please share more code.  the error seems to be var symGrp

Here is the code here - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_aCr3ALZgqLwFO4D8VXZvr6RMTlItYPsAiQTihY8Nyk/edit?usp=sharing
